# How can I get "min_tag_id" to get a list of recently tagged media from instagram api

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I have just use the below link considering the official documentation.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

But, even if I dont use max_tag_id/min_tag_id as a parameter, it returns the error message :

```
 {"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}
```

How can I get the max_tag_id/min_tag_id to be able to get a list of tagged media ?

I have also used the link giving a random number for min_tag_id like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snowy/media/recent?access_token=272673723.8eadebe.2243d71d379541118c9f24bc221a99e5&min_tag_id=10
```

It gives me the below error message :

```
"error_message": "min_id must not be a media id."
```

How can I get the media ids to use min_tag_id ? My main problem is get the tagged media from instagram api. But It sucks.

My status is **Sandbox Mode**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access lastest 20 posts in sandbox mode, one u go to live mode, you will see pagination data with min_tag_id and max_tag_id

> The behavior of the API when you are in sandbox mode is the same as
>   when your app is live, but comes with the following restrictions:
>
> - Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from each sandbox user
> - Reduced API rate limits

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Comment: I don't get even a tagged post. It gives just error message. As you see, my problem is not the size of post that I received. The problem is I don't get any of them.

Comment: in sandbox, you will only see your posts and any other sandbox user u have added. you add a post with the hashtag, then only that will show in API response, its limitation of sandbox mode

Comment: Oh!  I didn't know that. Thanks I have tested the link using a tag that I used in my instagram account.